# Getting error as "could not find driver" using PDO in PHP and sql server 2016

Tags: php, pdo, unixodbc

I need a small help to config pdo_odbc in my application. below are the details:

1. Server name: Linux red hat 6 (Linux XXXServer 2.6.32-754.25.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 20 15:07:26 EST 2019 x86_64 )
2. PHP Info: PHP Version 7.3.16

when I run below code is can not show ODBC but i added code ‍`extension=pdo_odbc.so` in `php.ini` file:
`php -r ' print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers()); '`
OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mysql
    [1] => sqlite
)
```

Also, I am trying to run below config command:
`./configure --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr/local`

but its getting error:
`bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`

Thank you in advance

Comment: `./configure` is a command to build PHP from sources. Why don't you just look for `pdo_odbc` in your distro package manager?

Comment: php -i | grep PDO
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, sqlite
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
PDO Driver for SQLite 3.x => enabled

Comment: Here ODBC driver is not enabled so can you please help me.

Comment: [Searching Packages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-packages_and_package_groups#sec-Searching_Packages) and [Installing Packages](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/sec-installing) in Red Hat 6.